# Prove that if $b - k$ divides $a - k^n$ for all $k \ne b$, then $a = b^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, n \in \mathbb N$. Prove that if $b - k$ divides $a - k^n$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $k \ne b$, then $a = b^n$.

My approach inspired by [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988167/if-for-all-n-in-bbbn-an-n-divides-bn-n-then-a-b) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4040/164272) goes somewhat like:

In order to take care of the exponential $k^n$, let's use the Fermat Little Theorem, so let's pick a prime $p$ and consider $k = a^p$.

Then taking $$b - k | a - k^n$$
modulo $p$ implies:
$$b - a^p | a - a^{pn} \mod p$$
$$b - a | a - a^n \mod p$$

And here I got stuck. I understand that we have much freedom in our choice of $p$, so we can take it as large as we want, which would also imply that it's not a divisor of $b - a$ nor $a - a^n$, but still I don't understand how I can deduce the equality of values from their divisibility modulo $p$.

Comment: I think you have to restrict $k>1$, as $(b-1)\mid (a-1^{10})\not \Rightarrow b=a^{10}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=b^n+c$,

then   $a-k^n=b^n-k^n+c$ is divisible by $b-k$ for arbitrary integer k not equal to $b$.

Since $b^n-k^n$ is divisible by $b-k$,

therefore $c$ is divisible by $b-k$.

Since $k$ is arbitrary integer not equal to $b$, $b-k$ is an arbitrary nonzero integer.

If $c \neq 0$, the conclusion that $c$ is divisible by any nonzero integer is impossible because $c$ is not divisible by $2c$.

Thus $c$ must be $0$  and $a=b^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $k>b+|b^n-a|$. Then notice that since $b-k \mid a-b^n$ and $b-k \mid b^n-k^n$, $b-k \mid b^n-a$, which implies that either $|b-k|\leq|b^n-a|$ or $b^n-a=0$.

But $b-k<-|b^n-a|\leq 0$, which implies that $|b-k|>|b^n-a|$. So $b^n-a=0$ and $a=b^n$.